# Bootstrap carousel is jumping

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having trouble figuring out why my Bootstrap carousel is not having the images transition smoothly.  Below is a link to my website -

https://money-lender-tapir-15475.bitballoon.com

If scroll down a little bit and watch the pictures transition you'll see that they load above the bottom of the div then slide down.  How do I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: For me everything looks fine. Which browser did you use?

Comment: Keep same height for all carousel images to fix this issue.

Comment: @RAN what is the best way to resize them all online to be the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this to your css should fix the issue.

```
body {
  padding-top: 50px; /* small fix */
}
.carousel-inner {
  height: calc(100vh - 50px); /* full screen */
}
.carousel-inner > .item > img {
  width: 100%; /* to make smaller images look full */
}
```

You need to give a fixed height so that the images don't jump because of difference in image size.

**For smaller screens you need to add media query**

```
@media (max-width: 767px){
    .carousel-inner{
        height: auto;
    }
}
```

Comment: So this fixes the issue when I leave the browser full screen but when I shrink the viewport the pictures and carousel div get all messed up.  Why is it doing that and how do i fix it?

Comment: @TommyLonergan, updated the answer. You needed to add a media query.